# как сделать случайную генерацию уровня?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

я делаю я делаю пошаговою стратегию на python с использованием pygame,
как мне реализовать случайную генерацию мира в клетках? Она должна работать следующим образом: у нас есть сетка, на ней группами (от 2 до 5 клеток) генерируются клетки разных цветов.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

W = 600
H = 600

cell_qty = 20
cell_size = 30

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W,H))
pygame.display.set_caption("стратегия")

WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
COLOR = (255,0,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


speed = 5


for y in range(cell_qty):
    for x in range(cell_qty):
        rect = pygame.draw.rect(sc, WHITE,(x*cell_size, y*cell_size, cell_size, cell_size),1)

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    pygame.display.update()
   
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Что вы пробовали и где у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: я пробовал создавать квадраты по случайным координатам, назначая на каждую клетку свой квадрат, но так алгоритм был максимально не оптимизирован.

Comment: У вас будет около 100 разных цветов 400 клеток/3,5 среднее кол-во в группе?

Comment: да, но среднее кол-во придётся округлить

Comment: Я бы разбил квадрат на четыре кривые, но почти равные части, так легче заполнять и сканировать какую-то область. Которые, в принципе, можно менять от уровня к уровню, чтоб глаз не улавливал. И использовал классы спрайтов и группы и обход каждого графа в глубину.